# Error using require with react native in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, require

I'm trying to do this:

```
<Image source={require(`../../imagens/cards${result.color}.png`)}/>
```

in that path I have 5 png files: cardsgreen, cardsyellow, cardspurple,...

result.color gives me an string which is purple and it doesn't work because require doesn't allow it and I want to know if there is another way to do it, I have also tried:

```
source={{ uri: `../../imagens/cards${result.color}.png` }}
```

and it didn't work either, the image just didn't open in that case

error: The development server returned response error code: 500, calls to require expect exactly 1 string literal argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try yo use:

```
  var images = {
                blue: require('../imageblue.png'),
                red: require('../imagered.png')
            }
<Image source={images[this.state.imgColor]} key={images[this.state.imgColor]} />
```

ImgColor should be your result.color.
Don't forget to use key on image, else the state will not change the color it dynamically.

Comment: it doesn't work in that way, i have tryed '../../imagens/cards'+result.color+'.png' too and it didn't work

Comment: Then try to compose your path before to use it on source. If you have to reload it use it as a state. Like `this.state.imgPath = '../../imagens/cards/' + result.color.toString() + '.png'` and use this imgPath in the require.

Comment: Yes, i did it, actually using toString(), and after tryed to use it in the require, same error

Comment: The only solution that i can think is to do if(result.color === 'purple') then i use require('../imagens/cardspurple.png')

Comment: @PedroMartinsMelo I updated the answer, it's more elegant and dinamyc then the `if` case